# Suspicious ICMP network traffic from public IPs on private GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

After enabling network policy logging on a vpc-native cluster, it turned out that some suspicious ICMP traffic is blocked.

According to the log json payload, the Internet ICMP traffic is somehow reaching pods (including those which are not exposed by any service or ingress). Example log below:

```
"src": {
  "instance": "redacted_public_ip"
},
"node_name": "redacted_node_name",
"count": 1,
"disposition": "deny",
"dest": {
  "workload_name": "redacted_workload_name",
  "workload_kind": "ReplicaSet",
  "pod_namespace": "redacted_pod_namespace",
  "namespace": "redacted_namespace",
  "pod_name": "redacted_pod_name"
},
"connection": {
  "protocol": "icmp",
  "dest_ip": "redacted_private_pod_ip",
  "direction": "ingress",
  "src_ip": "redacted_public_ip"
}
```

There are multiple entries like the one above, and public IPs are owned by multiple different organisations and located in different countries. What might be the next step with investigating this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simply block ICMP unless you really need it. There are two basic types of ICMP, one used for routing and the other for ping-pong messages. You do not need either one enabled.

The next tip is that there is nothing to investigate. The public Internet will poke and prod every public IP address non-stop. Otherwise, you will need to deploy a firewall and blocklists to block known bad actors.